# Outlook stalls when sending multiple emails

Tags: smtp, outlook

I have an issue very specific to outlook and a single email domain.  I work for an email and website hosting company.

When sending one email to a foreign domain, no issues.  When sending more then one email, the first email is sent fine but stalls sending the rest and sits in the outbox.  Wireshark shows, both from the client and hosting server, that outbound authentication happens, first email is sent, second MAIL FROM: appears then it just does nothing.  But,  if I use a different email account from a different domain hosted from the same server it works fine.

Any thoughts.

DB it

Comment: A throttling policy on the smtp server ? do you control/own the smtp server ?

Comment: Ty for replying!  We own the server and the SMTP.  I did think of throttling but that's turned off.  If you send internally to your own domain, it works fine. Also, the hosted server, geographically speaking, is at a different location.  There are 1-3 firewalls between you and the host.  And it is happening at home, too.  Fun fun.

Comment: As it happen at home too, to send do you use a smarthost (aka your server use your ISP's server) in example ? or it use the MX directly ? Can you check the sendqueue from the server too

Comment: Have you tried enabling Outlook's built-in logging?